# Using mahout in java code, not cli

Tags: java, classification, mahout

i want to be able to build a model using java, i am able to do so with CLI as folowing:

```
    ./mahout trainlogistic --input Candy-Crush.twtr.csv \
       --output ./model \
       --target hd_click --categories 2 \
       --predictors click_frequency country_code ctr      device_price_range hd_conversion  time_of_day num_clicks phone_type twitter is_weekend app_entertainment app_wallpaper app_widgets arcade books_and_reference brain business cards casual comics communication education entertainment finance game_wallpaper game_widgets health_and_fitness health_fitness libraries_and_demo libraries_demo lifestyle media_and_video media_video medical music_and_audio news_and_magazines news_magazines personalization photography productivity racing shopping social sports sports_apps sports_games tools transportation travel_and_local weather app_entertainment_percentage app_wallpaper_percentage app_widgets_percentage arcade_percentage books_and_reference_percentage brain_percentage business_percentage cards_percentage casual_percentage comics_percentage communication_percentage education_percentage entertainment_percentage finance_percentage game_wallpaper_percentage game_widgets_percentage health_and_fitness_percentage health_fitness_percentage libraries_and_demo_percentage libraries_demo_percentage lifestyle_percentage media_and_video_percentage media_video_percentage medical_percentage music_and_audio_percentage news_and_magazines_percentage news_magazines_percentage personalization_percentage photography_percentage productivity_percentage racing_percentage shopping_percentage social_percentage sports_apps_percentage sports_games_percentage sports_percentage tools_percentage transportation_percentage travel_and_local_percentage weather_percentage reads_magazine_sum reads_magazine_count interested_in_gardening_sum interested_in_gardening_count kids_birthday_coming_sum kids_birthday_coming_count job_seeker_sum job_seeker_count friends_sum friends_count married_sum married_count charity_donor_sum charity_donor_count student_sum student_count interested_in_real_estate_sum interested_in_real_estate_count sports_fan_sum sports_fan_count bascketball_sum bascketball_count interested_in_politics_sum interested_in_politics_count gamer_sum gamer_count activist_sum activist_count traveler_sum traveler_count likes_soccer_sum likes_soccer_count interested_in_celebs_sum interested_in_celebs_count auto_racing_sum auto_racing_count age_group_sum age_group_count healthy_lifestyle_sum healthy_lifestyle_count interested_in_finance_sum interested_in_finance_count sports_teams_usa_sum sports_teams_usa_count interested_in_deals_sum interested_in_deals_count business_oriented_sum business_oriented_count interested_in_cooking_sum interested_in_cooking_count music_lover_sum music_lover_count beauty_sum beauty_count follows_fashion_sum follows_fashion_count likes_wrestling_sum likes_wrestling_count name_sum name_count shopper_sum shopper_count golf_sum golf_count vegetarian_sum vegetarian_count dating_sum dating_count interested_in_fashion_sum interested_in_fashion_count interested_in_news_sum interested_in_news_count likes_tennis_sum likes_tennis_count male_sum male_count interested_in_cars_sum interested_in_cars_count follows_bloggers_sum follows_bloggers_count entertainment_sum entertainment_count interested_in_books_sum interested_in_books_count has_kids_sum has_kids_count interested_in_movies_sum interested_in_movies_count musicians_sum musicians_count tech_oriented_sum tech_oriented_count female_sum female_count has_pet_sum has_pet_count practicing_sports_sum practicing_sports_count \
       --types      numeric         word         numeric  word               word           word        numeric    word       word    word        numeric       \
       --features 100 --passes 1 --rate 50
```

i cant understand the 20 news group example because its to big to learn from.
can anyone give me a code that is doing the same as the cli command?

to clarify:

i need something like this:

```
    model.train(1,0,"monday",6,44,1,7,4,6,78,7,3,4,6,........,"good");
    model.train(1,0,"sunday",6,44,5,7,9,2,4,6,78,7,3,4,6,........,"bad");
    model.train(1,0,"monday",4,99,2,4,6,3,4,6,........,"good");

    model.writeTofile("myModel.model");
```

PLESE DO NOT ANSWER IF YOU ARE NOT FAMILIAR WITH CLASSIFICATION AND ONLY WANT TO TELL ME HOW TO EXECUTE CLI COMMAND FROM JAVA

Comment: i don't understand your problem. what do you mean by _i want to build be able to build a model_?

you say that you are able to do so with CLI but in the last sentence you ask for code that does something as a cli command.

Comment: yes... i need the code to do it.

Comment: but you tell use you are able to do it. then why should we write your code?

Comment: because i have a production environment and i cant run there cli commands, i need to do it in pure java

Comment: why can't you run cli commands?

Comment: because i run code, automatic, i wont create files and go to run it from cli, its production

Comment: what command are you trying to run EXACTLY? what you you tried to use java for this? why do you even want to use java for this? what have you tried yet? we help you with your code but we won't write the whole code for you

Comment: as i said, my production is java,i actually need to train the model with data from MongoDB, so i need a simple code that take 5-10 lines of data and creates a model.

Comment: what do you mean by _train the model_

Comment: by train a model i mean to create a model, are yoe familiar with data mining/classification/mahout/weka at all?

Comment: no i'm not! but when you can solve a problem with cli you should not use java! java is to complex for this and you can't be sure it will run on your production environment

Comment: then please stop writing here. i am asking for help about mahout, not about how not to run java. mahout is a java library.

Answer (score 7):

I am not 100% familiar with the Mahout API (I agree that documentation is very sparse) so I can only give pointers, but I hope it helps:

The Java source code for the `trainlogistic` example can actually be found in the `mahout-examples` library - it's on maven [0] (in `org.apache.mahout.classifier.sgd.TrainLogistic`). I suppose if you wanted to, you could just use the exact same source code, but it depends on a couple of utility classes in the `mahout-examples` library (and it's not very clean, either).

The class performing the training in this example is `org.apache.mahout.classifier.sgd.OnlineLogisticRegression` [1], although considering the large number of predictor variables you have you might want to use the `AdaptiveLogisticRegression` [2] (same package), which uses a number of `OnlineLogisticRegression`s internally. But you have to see for yourself which works best with your data.

The API is fairly straightforward, there's a `train` method which takes a `Vector` of your input data and a `classify` method to test your model, as well as `learningRate` and others to change the model's parameters.

To save the model to disk like the command line tool does, use the `org.apache.mahout.classifier.sgd.ModelSerializer`, which has a straightforward API to write and read your model. (There's also `write` and `readFields` methods in the OLR class itself, but frankly, I'm not sure what they do or if there's a difference to `ModelSerializer` - they're not documented either.)

Lastly, aside from the source code in `mahout-examples`, here's two other example of using the Mahout API directly, that might be useful [3, 4].

Sources:

[0] http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/mahout/mahout-examples/0.8/

[1] http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/mahout/mahout-core/org/apache/mahout/classifier/sgd/OnlineLogisticRegression.html

[2] http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/mahout/mahout-core/org/apache/mahout/classifier/sgd/AdaptiveLogisticRegression.html

[3] http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/mahout-user/201206.mbox/%3CCAJwFCa3X2fL_SRxT7f7v9uMjS3Tc9WrT7vuMQCVXyH71k0H0zQ@mail.gmail.com%3E

[4] http://skife.org/mahout/2013/02/14/first_steps_with_mahout.html

Answer (score 1):

This blog has a good post about how to do training and classification with Mahout Java API: http://nigap.blogspot.com/2012/02/bayes-algorithm-with-apache-mahout.html

Comment: This tutorial is good but it is based on Mahout 0.5 which was released a long ago. :(

Answer (score -2):

You could use Runtime.exec to execute the same cmd line from java.

The simple approach is:

`Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/bash -ic \"<path_to_mahout>/mahout trainlogistic --input Candy-Crush.twtr.csv "
                + "--output ./model "
                + "--target hd_click --categories 2 "
                + "--predictors click_frequency country_code ctr      device_price_range hd_conversion  time_of_day num_clicks phone_type twitter is_weekend app_entertainment app_wallpaper app_widgets arcade books_and_reference brain business cards casual comics communication education entertainment finance game_wallpaper game_widgets health_and_fitness health_fitness libraries_and_demo libraries_demo lifestyle media_and_video media_video medical music_and_audio news_and_magazines news_magazines personalization photography productivity racing shopping social sports sports_apps sports_games tools transportation travel_and_local weather app_entertainment_percentage app_wallpaper_percentage app_widgets_percentage arcade_percentage books_and_reference_percentage brain_percentage business_percentage cards_percentage casual_percentage comics_percentage communication_percentage education_percentage entertainment_percentage finance_percentage game_wallpaper_percentage game_widgets_percentage health_and_fitness_percentage health_fitness_percentage libraries_and_demo_percentage libraries_demo_percentage lifestyle_percentage media_and_video_percentage media_video_percentage medical_percentage music_and_audio_percentage news_and_magazines_percentage news_magazines_percentage personalization_percentage photography_percentage productivity_percentage racing_percentage shopping_percentage social_percentage sports_apps_percentage sports_games_percentage sports_percentage tools_percentage transportation_percentage travel_and_local_percentage weather_percentage reads_magazine_sum reads_magazine_count interested_in_gardening_sum interested_in_gardening_count kids_birthday_coming_sum kids_birthday_coming_count job_seeker_sum job_seeker_count friends_sum friends_count married_sum married_count charity_donor_sum charity_donor_count student_sum student_count interested_in_real_estate_sum interested_in_real_estate_count sports_fan_sum sports_fan_count bascketball_sum bascketball_count interested_in_politics_sum interested_in_politics_count gamer_sum gamer_count activist_sum activist_count traveler_sum traveler_count likes_soccer_sum likes_soccer_count interested_in_celebs_sum interested_in_celebs_count auto_racing_sum auto_racing_count age_group_sum age_group_count healthy_lifestyle_sum healthy_lifestyle_count interested_in_finance_sum interested_in_finance_count sports_teams_usa_sum sports_teams_usa_count interested_in_deals_sum interested_in_deals_count business_oriented_sum business_oriented_count interested_in_cooking_sum interested_in_cooking_count music_lover_sum music_lover_count beauty_sum beauty_count follows_fashion_sum follows_fashion_count likes_wrestling_sum likes_wrestling_count name_sum name_count shopper_sum shopper_count golf_sum golf_count vegetarian_sum vegetarian_count dating_sum dating_count interested_in_fashion_sum interested_in_fashion_count interested_in_news_sum interested_in_news_count likes_tennis_sum likes_tennis_count male_sum male_count interested_in_cars_sum interested_in_cars_count follows_bloggers_sum follows_bloggers_count entertainment_sum entertainment_count interested_in_books_sum interested_in_books_count has_kids_sum has_kids_count interested_in_movies_sum interested_in_movies_count musicians_sum musicians_count tech_oriented_sum tech_oriented_count female_sum female_count has_pet_sum has_pet_count practicing_sports_sum practicing_sports_count "
                + "--types      numeric         word         numeric  word               word           word        numeric    word       word    word        numeric       "
                + "--features 100 --passes 1 --rate 50\"");`

If you opt for this, then I suggest reading this first:
[When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=4)

This way the application will run in a diffent process.

Additionally you can follow the section 'Integration with your application' from the following site: 
[Recomender Documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAHOUT/Recommender+Documentation)

Also this is a good reference on writing a recomender:
[Introducing Apache Mahout](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-mahout/index.html)

Hope this helps. 
Cheers

Comment: i know how to use java Runtime. this is not what i asked for.

Comment: @DimaGoltsman Sorry about this, just trying to help. I thought that you wanted to make it automatic and not run it by hand. You did not mentioned you are not allowed to create new processes. Anyway, just because your question was not clear, does not mean my answer was wrong.